# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to MongodB and nodejs
GET working fine (getting empty array), I'm getting this err msg when try POST in postman for "categories"

**categories route of expressjs**
https://codeshare.io/YLdm0Y

**app.js**
https://codeshare.io/QnWK0x

**err msg of console**

```
 MongoDB connected successfully
(node:6668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\routes\categories.js:16:20
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\express\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6668) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [BodyParser middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html).

Add this after line 3:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: hey there, i am having issue on form-data. here's my question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117682/form-data-field-value-is-undefined-null-in-nodejs